# Configuration system failed to initialize in window service

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

i have developed the windows service with log4net for logging the exceptions.

here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>


  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
    </configSections>
  </configuration>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="Error" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\\windowslogfile.txt"/>


        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
        <countDirection value="1" />
        <maximumFileSize value="4096KB" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender.MinimalLock" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%newlineDate[%date] ThreadID[%thread] Level[%-5level] Logger[%logger]] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
      </appender>
  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Service1" value="Te.Service"/>
    <add key="Service2" value="CaseWorksCachingServiceme"/>
    <add key="Service2" value="CaseWorksCachingService"/>

  </appSettings>


</configuration>
```

hi , i am unable to run the windows service properly.the error logged in log file is

> Configuration system failed to initialize.

Comment: _"the service doesn't run"_ - isn't helpful.  What error are you getting when attempting to use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`?

Comment: The service doesn't run,error is the service doesn't run on local system.

Comment: _"The service doesn't run,error is the service doesn't run on local system"_ - If I could down-vote you again I would.

Comment: sorry,actullay i am doing the automatically service going  to be run when i am installing the service.but the service doesn't run automatically ,but when i try to start the service it showing error like the service doesn't run.

Comment: hi @MickyD,the error is Configuration system failed to initialize

Comment: hi @MickyD, The problem with app.config file ,now i change my question ,please refer once.

Comment: You really need to undo your recent changes.  Before  you had _code but no config file_; then _code and config file_; now it is just the _config file_.  You need both in order to paint a complete picture

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicate key in your appsettings, namely `Service2`

Comment: hi, icahnged that one ,but still now ,i got same error

Answer (score 0):

> Configuration system failed to initialize

I suspect that your Windows service does not have permissions to access **C:\windowslogfile.txt**

Either:

- grant the appropriate permissions to this folder for the service account the service is running in or
- simply remove log4net.

Comment: hi, the log file is created i.e not problem ,in log file the error logged is the Configuration system failed to initialize

Comment: @GOPALYADAV I very much doubt that.  Get rid of log4net and be done with it

Answer (score 0):

You have `<configuration>` as both parent and child tag, Witch is incorrect.

Remove child `<configSections>` tag , add `<configSections>` directly in parent  as follows,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
      <configSections>
              ...
      </configSections>
  </configuration>
```

It seems Copy&Pest error.